# Android - Is there a way to register my Activity and Service other than Manifest file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-manifest

Actually I want to know the other way if exist to register my Activity and Service similar to  LocalBroadcast Reciever.

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: yes I read your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**, you cannot "register" your `Activity`s and `Service`s anywhere other than the manifest.

Now I'll explain the long answer, the **WHY**. The Android architecture divides an application into 4 top-level components:

- `Activity`
- `Service`
- `BroadcastReceiver`
- `ContentProvider`

The idea is that developers can allow *some* components of their app to be used by other applications. You may have noticed how an image or a PDF file can be opened by more than one app. Or say you need the functionality of the camera or browser, then you don't need to create your own camera or browser app, just send an `Intent` to start an available, existing app.

Anyhow, the point is that such is the Android architecture, and you have these *components*. Each top-level component *must* be specified in the manifest file, which acts as a sort of summary or record of all components of an app.

The `LocalBroadcastManager` class that you have mentioned is meant for sending *intra-app* broadcasts, i.e. broadcasts that are *local* to an app. The `sendBroadcast()` method that can be called from an `Activity` or `Service` sends a *global* broadcast that propagates to other apps, i.e. it is an *inter-app* broadcast which can and indeed is heard by `BroadcastReceiver`s of other apps that filter the same `Intent`.

Now because the `LocalBroadcastManager` is, well, *local*, and by design it is not meant to interact with anything outside its own app, therefore it is **NOT** a top-level component. And hence it need not be declared in the manifest file. It is instead registered & de-registered in the lifecycle callbacks of an `Activity` or `Service`. It is not similarly possible to "register" an `Activity` or `Service`, which are *major* components of an Android app.

I hope this was useful.